# What does the "rc" in a npm package version structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, versioning, semantic-versioning

I was wondering what the `rc` in `2.2.0-rc.0` stands for. Does it mean that its production ready?

Comment: release canidate.

Comment: you should ask the package to ensure they are production ready.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means it is a release candidate.  meaning it is ready to go out, but it isn't proven yet so it's not ready to be marked as a stable release quite yet. You can think of it as a mature beta release.

If no bugs are found and it is deemed (by the developers/community) to be stable it can be marked as a full release.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the link as well :) New to the software development scene so not aware of these cycles and processes haha.

Comment: If a bug is found in an RC e.g. _"RC 3 broke foo"_, usually it will be fixed and then there will be a _"RC 4, foo fixed"_, and the new RC would have the same feature set, signatures, etc, so dependencies on it don't need to be otherwise modified

Answer (score 9):

Generally it means, "release candidate", meaning it's not production ready, but nearly so, and is generally dispensed with the intention that early-adopters/users will file/fix bugs and issues to test the software.